# Android: Placing a TextView centered around a specified position in XML

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that can have a few different values, and is updated runtime (in Java code).

However, I need this TextView to retain its center point, so that when the text in that TextView is updated, it is always center justified. It should be centered around a point which is not the center of the screen or anything else, so setting gravity only will not help.

As the values that it may contain are already defined, I could try with the longest one first, position it to the correct top left position and set its gravity to center. In this case every shorter in length text should fit correctly.
However, I would like to know if there is better approach, for cases when the values are not known beforehand.

This TextView is placed below an ImageView and it could take the whole screen width (nothing else is placed left or right to it).

Note: I guess it could be also possible to position it every time to a new X axis position, whenever the text is changed, but I don't think it is a nice solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` and set `android:gravity` to `center_horizontal`.

This way the View is stretched all the way horizontally, and the content (the text) will be centered. If the content changes, it will still be centered.

One thing that many people don't realize is the difference between `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`. The first one defines the alignment of the content inside itself, the other one defines alignment of itself relative to its parent.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help, because it is not the horizontal center of the parent view where the text should be centered. It is a different point, which can be 1/3 of the parent layout or the screen. So I need to specify a point for the center of the TextView